# How to add a primary key to Visio diagram programatically with C#

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

I was wondering if it is even possible.
I am using the Visio Drawing contorl + the MODELEng lib.
I have something like:

```
        IVMEEntity entity = GetEntity();
        IVMEAttribute attribNew = entity.CreateAttribute();
        attribNew.PhysicalName = attrib.AttributeName;
        attribNew.ConceptualName = attrib.AttributeName;
        attribNew.AllowNulls = !attrib.AttributeNotNull;
```

And it works fine to add attrbiutes (think of columns) to the current entity.
It can't add a column as a primary key. As far as I know I should use

```
attribNew.AttributeAnnotations
```

in some way but I can't really understand how.

Comment: What type of object is entity here?

Comment: Sorry, it is IVMEEntity, I updated my question, thanks! Any idea if it is even possible?

Comment: @JMK, have you been in such a situation?